# DOMException: Registration failed - push service error

Tags: push-notification

## KEY :

applicationServerPublicKey from :https://web-push-codelab.appspot.com/

## JS CODE:

```
function subscribeUser() {
     const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
     swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
          userVisibleOnly: true,
          applicationServerKey: applicationServerKey
     }).then(function(subscription) {
console.log('User is subscribed.');
        alert('subscribe ok');
        isSubscribed = true;
}).catch(function(err) {
    alert('subscribe error:'+ err);
});
}
```

## Result

When I use a web browser to access the site, click on the subscription function when there is no problem.

When I use the Andrews mobile phone to visit the site, click on the subscription function when the error,

the wrong suggested: registration failed - push service error android

## SO

I found all the documents did not find a solution, please help me!

Comment: Any solution for this yet?